# Object from class library not contains methods

Tags: c#

Trying to build and use class library in C#.

Creating class library:
File->New Project->Windows->Classic Desktop->Class Library
Code:

```
namespace ClassLibrary2
{
    public class Class1
    {

        public static long Add(long i, long j)
        {
            return (i + j);
        }

    }
}
```

Trying to consume it from console application:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClassLibrary2.Class1 c = new Class1();
            c. //no Add function


        }
    }
}
```

But `c` object not contains `Add` function. Why? How how to fix it?

Comment: change with ClassLibrary2.Class1 c = new ClassLibrary2.Class1();

Comment: @AlexPashkin: That's not going to make a static method available as if it were an instance method...

Comment: @JonSkeet it makes the code work :) More elegant approach is using Add method as extension.

Comment: @AlexPashkin: No, it doesn't. A call to `c.Add` still wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Add` is a static method. You can't call static methods "via" instances in C#. That has nothing to do with it being in a different library.

You can call the method as:

```
long result = ClassLibrary2.Class1.Add(10, 20);
```

or if you actually have a `using` directive for `ClassLibrary2` (it's unclear from the question):

```
long result = Class1.Add(10L, 20L);
```

Alternatively, change the method to be an instance method, if that's what you wanted - at which point you'd be able to call `c.Add(10L, 20L)`.

Answer (score 1):

You declared Class1  as static, then, you don't need an instance to use it.

```
ClassLibrary2.Add(1, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add in static method. You must call it like static method:

```
Class1.Add(1,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If You intent to make it Instance specific remove the static

```
namespace ClassLibrary2
{
    public class Class1
    {

        public long Add(long i, long j)
        {
            return (i + j);
        }

    }
}
```